# How can I convert the values of an input field from a string to an integer with javascript? How can I use the parsInt() function?

Tags: javascript, parsing

I am making a timer with javascript and I have a form where a user inputs the minutes and seconds then when they click submit a getTime() function is ran so a time variable is created.  It is recognizing the time variable as a string not a number and I am getting NaN.  How can I get the values of the id's "mNumbers" and "sNumbers" through the parsInt() to convert them to numbers and get rid of the NaN error?  Or is there a better way?

Here is the html form code:

```
     <form id="timer" onSubmit="return getTime();">
        <input type="number" name="Mintues" id="mNumber">Minutes <br >
        <input type="number" name="Seconds" id="sNumber">Seconds <br >
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
    </form>
```

here is the javascript I have:

```
function getTime() {
var minutes= parsInt($('#mNumber').val() * 10000);
var seconds=parsInt($('#sNumber').val() *1000);
var time = minutes + seconds;
return time;
}
```

Comment: it is **`parseInt`**

Comment: Did you ever look in the console?

Comment: I believe English is not the OP natural language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getTime() {
    var minutes, seconds, time;
    minutes = (parseInt( $('#mNumber').val(), 10) || 0) * 10000;
    seconds = (parseInt( $('#sNumber').val(), 10) || 0) * 1000;
    time = minutes + seconds;
    return time
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I tried using this for my getTime function but it is now saying "undefined".

Comment: Sorry, I did a typo in previous code. I used same index for minutes and seconds. Now it's fixed in the code above.

Also look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/nrdMX/1/ . If you have jQuery, try to use "onready".

Seems like function is defined in wrong scope.

Answer (score 2):

First parse the string `parseInt` (with an `e`), then do math like multiplication:

```
parseInt($('#mNumber').val()) * 10000;
```

Now if somebody uses 2 digit time like `09` you will get surprising results with some browsers, so it's better to provide the radix... `parseInt(..., 10)`.

Personally I would move the whole math stuff at the end, it's a lot more readable:

```
var time = 10000*minutes + 1000*seconds;
```